# Trying to move an image via transform: translateZ()

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move an img in a 3d space by using transform: translateZ().

here is a picture of what i have currently. [image: box]

im trying to move the img icons around the box.

Here is what ive tried:

- Using transform: translateZ(100px) in the id selectors for each img.
- Using .box img:nthchild(7) {translateZ(100px)}.
- Tried adding perspective to the .box class.

```css
#animated-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 67%;
  top: 35%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  animation: rotate 60s infinite;
  z-index: 100;
}

.box div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #272727b2;
  border: 1px solid #55FFEB;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 5px rgb(85, 255, 235);
  transition: all 1s ease;
  z-index: 99;
}

#html-png {
  top: 40%;
  left: 60%;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  animation: crazy 45s infinite;
  transform: translateY(1000px);
}

#js-png {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 35%;
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  animation: crazy 45s infinite;
}

#css-png {
  left: 10%;
  top: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  animation: crazy 45s infinite;
}

#boot-png {
  left: 10%;
  top: -17%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  animation: crazy 45s infinite;
}

#git-png {
  left: 10%;
  top: -17%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  animation: crazy 45s infinite;
}

#box-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: -20%;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- animated floating box -->
<section id="animated-box">
  <div class="box">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <img id="html-png" src="imgs/html5.png" alt="">
    <img id="css-png" src="imgs/css.png" alt="">
    <img id="js-png" src="imgs/javascript.png" alt="">
    <img id="boot-png" src="imgs/boot.png" alt="">
    <img id="git-png" src="imgs/git.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="box-text">Click cube to see the code running this page</div>
</section>
```

```
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

any advice would be welcome, thanks in advance.